# Rails 2.3.8 Redirecting: redirect_to back or default results in infinte log-in loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
  map.connect "/session", :controller => "sessions", :action => "new"
```

so, I decided to add the above line to my routes, because sometimes, the user may end up on /session somehow...

but when I did that, after I try logging in, the

redirect_back_or_default('/')

bit in sessions/create sends me back to /sessions instead of the previous url I actually tried to go to. 
le code:

```
def redirect_back_or_default(default)
  if not session[:return_to] =~ /session/
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default) 
  else
    redirect_to(default)
  end
  session[:return_to] = nil
end
```

Comment: As a matter of style, flip your `if` conditions. Having an `if (not this) else` introduces a double negative, as the else is equivalent to `if (not not this)`.

Comment: You could also use `unless`.